# Does $S_N=\sum_{k=0}^{k=N}X_{k}$, for $X_{k+1}=\frac{1}{k!}BX_{k}B$ with $X_0=A$ and diagonal $B$, have a closed-form solution?

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Assume that $A$ is a square matrix with complex entries and $B$ is a complex diagonal matrix (not necessarily invertible). Consider the following matrix sequence

$X_{k+1}=\frac{1}{k!}BX_{k}B$

with $X_0=A$.

**Question 1:** Is there any closed form solution for $S_N=\sum_{k=0}^{k=N}X_{k}$?

**Question 2:** Is there any relation between eigenvalues of $S_N$ and $A$ and $B$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\Sk{\sum_{k=0}^n}
\def\SK{{\large\sum_{k=0}^n}}
$In general, diagonal matrices in an expression can be replaced by the Hadamard product $(\odot)$
$$\eqalign{
A &= \Diag{a} \\B &= \Diag{b} \\
AXB &= {ab^T}\odot X = X\odot{ab^T} \\
}$$
Note that this relationship utilizes the **transpose** and not the hermitian conjugate.

Applying this to the current problem $\,\LR{{\rm with}\;M=bb^T}\,$ yields
$$\eqalign{
\def\l{\ell}
X_{k+1} &= A\odot\fracLR{M^{\odot k}}{\prod_{\l=0}^k\l!} \\
S_n &= A\odot\SK\fracLR{M^{\odot k}}{\prod_{\l=0}^k\l!} \\
}$$
Note that the zeroth Hadamard power $M^{\odot 0}$ is the *all-ones* matrix rather than the identity matrix.

Substituting the [Barnes G-function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_G-function)
$${
G(k+2) = \prod_{\l=0}^k\l! \\
}$$
would give the above expressions a more concise appearance.

Comment: The series is not the expansion of exponential. In the scalar case, it is $a\big(1+b^2+\frac{b^4}{2!}+\frac{b^6}{2!3!}++\frac{b^8}{2!3!4!}+\cdots\big)$.

Comment: Oops! I didn't see the factorial in the definition of $X_{k+1}\;$